# Save string to integer array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

My task is to read from the match result from text file and put it in an `array`. However i have to use the match result to calculate the team performance. In order to do that, i have to convert the data type of the `result` in the `string` array to `int[]`.

Can anyone help me with this?

```
public LeagueMatch()
{

}
public LeagueMatch(String teamName, int[] result, String date, String opponent, int attendance,double ticketPrice,int awayFans) {
    this.teamName = teamName;
    this.result = result;
    this.date = date;
    this.opponent = opponent;
    this.attendance = attendance;
    this.ticketPrice = ticketPrice;
    this.awayFans = awayFans;
}

public LeagueMatch(String m)
{
    this.result = new int[2];
    String[] d = m.split(",");
    this.teamName=d[0];
    this.result=(d[1]); //there is an error here
    this.date=d[2];
    this.opponent=d[3];
    this.attendance=Integer.parseInt(d[4]);
    this.ticketPrice=Double.parseDouble(d[5]);
    this.awayFans=Integer.parseInt(d[6]);
}
```

Comment: Use Integer.parseInt(d[1]);

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a moment to read the guidelines for asking questions here in the [Help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using the string that you gave me

```
       String m = "Ashton Athletic,3-2,08/01/2011,Hounslow Harriers,10905,17.50,2013" ; 
   String[] d = m.split(",");
   String[] d1 = d[1].split("-") ;
   int[] result = new int[2];
   result[0]  = Integer.parseInt(d1[0]) ;
   result[1]  = Integer.parseInt(d1[1]) ;
   System.out.println(result[0]);
   System.out.println(result[1]);
```

This is my example you could modify it to fit in your case

it should be

```
String[] d1 = d[1].split("-") ;
  this.result[0]  = Integer.parseInt(d1[0]) ;
   this.result[1]  = Integer.parseInt(d1[1]) ;
```

Make sure that the variable int[] result is initilised

Comment: Ashton Athletic,3-2,08/01/2011,Hounslow Harriers,10905,17.50,2013

Comment: you're welcom , mark my answer as it's the correct answer @JavaNoob

Answer (score 0):

Try : this.result[0]=Integer.parseInt(d[1])

Comment: its has the error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "3-2" "

Comment: This is another issue. because value your getting is not an Integer.."3-2"